# How do I control rendering order of items in composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Alternative formulation of the question is:

Is there any other way apart from the order of adding items to the canvas of setting the rendering order>

The problem is that I want to change the map which was added first and the legend overlays the map so when I delete and replace the map the legend is underneath it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The next-to-last icon on the default toolbar in composer (two overlapping rectangles) will show a tooltip "Raise Selected Items". If you click the icon you get a choice of raise, lower, bring to front, send to back. Select the legend, click "bring to front" and you've got what you want.

Comment: That sort of works!  I sent the map to the back and one of the two overlays was exposed but the other was not. Bug?

Comment: try "Bring to front" on the overlay that's not exposed

Comment: Thanks Llaves! yes, I tried that first ;) I will play with it a bit more and if I can't get it to work I will file a bug report.  It might be a Mac/Maverick issue.