# Have Atlas sorting and filtering controls been removed in 2.4?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

In this diagram

[image]

the atlas generation tab of the print composer has several controls that I don't see in my version (2.4) of QGIS.  In particular the feature sorting and feature filtering, both of which sound like they might solve a problem I am having with Atlas generation see :[How do I control rendering order of items in composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89635/how-do-i-control-rendering-order-of-items-in-composer).

Is this a screen shot from an older version and these controls have been removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are still there in 2.4, they've just been renamed and moved slightly.

"Feature Filtering" is now "Filter With" and uses the one-line filter from the attribute table.

"Feature Sorting" is now just "Sort by" and is just below the file name expression.

[image]

Comment: Ah! the perils of keeping gui documentation up to date and unfortunately these don't do what I want.

Comment: The sort by should do what you need.